# Linking Domains to Profiles (PHP)

Tags: php, web-services, apache

I'd describe myself as a fairly advanced PHP programmer and I'm about to start work on a new project.

Basically, the user will purchase an account and create their own profile.  If they want, they can point their personal domain to their profile on our website.

Problem is... how do I get their domain to point to their profile?

Comment: What have you done?  `'they can point their personal domain to their profile on our website.'`  Does this mean you want to run a server that points domains to a particular instance in apache?

Comment: If you mean that each user will be registering their own domain and 'pointing' it to a page on your website, most domain registrars provide redirection (masked or not) to another domain free of charge.

Comment: It's going to be a website where photographers can create their own profile as their website, the default URL will be www.example.com/user/johndoe but he may have his own domain such as www.johndoe.com so how would I handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Set your project as the default virtualhost in apache (a virtual host that will be used for domains that don't have an own one). Don't know how you call it on apache.

Then check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in PHP to get the domain name. You can then redirect to the profile page or show it directly under that domain name.

People have to point their domain to your IP address (or point a subdomain to your IP using `CNAME`)

Comment: Sounds daunting :( Right I think I know what I need to do, would it be easier for users to do this? Is it just a case of pointing to my server?

Comment: Why daunting? This is much simpler than the way CNelson suggested because you don't have to set up a `VirtualHost` for every of your customers' domain. The way people point the domain to your server is the same. They could also use HTTP redirect or a frameset but as far as I understood your question this is not what you intend.

Comment: Ooo I see, so I could enter their domain name if they have one into my DB, if the users comes through the standard URL (users/johndoe) then redirect them to the domain in the DB...what if it's the other way round though?

Comment: Do you have any ideas on what I could do? Such as a step-by-step?

Answer (score 0):

On your side, you can create a virtual host in apache (or whatever) to map from usercustomdomain.com to their profile. A drirective like this may be enough for you:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot c:/htdocs
  ServerName usercustomdomain.com
  Redirect permanent / /profile.php?user=329
</VirtualHost>
```

On their side, using their DNS provider, they need to create a cname record for usercustomdomain.com to point to your webserver's address. This is pretty easy with go daddy or whatever but you'll probably want to give the user some documentation on your site on how to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, could I do this using the .htaccess file?

Comment: I don't believe you can setup a virtualhost under an htaccess file because the host processing happens before the path processing that would invoke the htaccess. After seeing Eliasdx's answer that will be the more flexible way to handle your situation.